# Using Input of Snowflake Function as the From clause

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

I have a function that takes a list of inputs to draft a query, it is dynamic SQL but not complex in any way the inputs directly pass through to the from and select clauses. In Snowflake, I cannot get it to allow me to use the name of the input as the table name. I tried using the `identifier` function, but still no luck. Here is the function if anyone has any ideas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_string
(p_table_name VARCHAR
,p_column_name VARCHAR
,p_where_column_name VARCHAR
,p_where_value VARCHAR
,p_order_by_YN VARCHAR
,p_order_by_column VARCHAR
)

RETURNS VARCHAR

AS

$$

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TRIM(upper(p_order_by_YN)) = 'Y' AND trim(p_order_by_column)> ' ' 
    THEN (SELECT as_array(p_column_name) from p_table_name where p_where_column_name = p_where_value order by p_order_by_column)
    ELSE (SELECT as_array(p_column_name) from p_table_name where p_where_column_name = p_where_value)
END AS V_CUR


$$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation doesn't explicitly call this out, I don't think the dynamic table name is possible with a UDF. However, it should be possible with a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html), which allows for "Dynamically creating a SQL statement and execute it."

See https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#dynamically-creating-a-sql-statement for a good example of this (reproduced below):

> Create the stored procedure. This procedure allows you to pass the
>   name of a table and get the number of rows in that table (equivalent
>   to select count(*) from table_name):
>
> ```
> create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
>     returns float 
>     not null
>     language javascript
>     as
>     $$
>     var row_count = 0;
>     // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
>     // Note that we uppercased the input parameter name.
>     var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;
>     // Run the statement.
>     var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
>            {
>            sqlText: sql_command
>            }
>         );
>     var res = stmt.execute();
>     // Get back the row count. Specifically, ...
>     // ... first, get the first (and in this case only) row from the
>     //  result set ...
>     res.next();
>     // ... then extract the returned value (which in this case is the
>     // number of rows in the table).
>     row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);
>     return row_count;
>     $$
>     ;
> ```
>
> Call the stored procedure:
>
> ```
> call get_row_count('stproc_test_table1');
> +---------------+
> | GET_ROW_COUNT |
> |---------------|
> |             3 |
> +---------------+
> ```
>
> Show the results from select count(*) for the same table:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stproc_test_table1;
> +----------+
> | COUNT(*) |
> |----------|
> |        3 |
> +----------+
> ```

Do understand that using the results of the procedure will be a little different from the function, see [Values Returned by Stored Procedures Are Not Directly Usable in SQL](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html#values-returned-by-stored-procedures-are-not-directly-usable-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the function is generating a SQL statement from the provided inputs. If that's the case, you can do this using a JavaScript UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_string
    (p_table_name VARCHAR
    ,p_column_name VARCHAR
    ,p_where_column_name VARCHAR
    ,p_where_value VARCHAR
    ,p_order_by_YN VARCHAR
    ,p_order_by_column VARCHAR
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
        var sql = "select " + P_COLUMN_NAME + " from " + P_TABLE_NAME + " where " + P_WHERE_COLUMN_NAME + " = ";

        if (isNaN(P_WHERE_VALUE)) {
            sql += "'" + P_WHERE_VALUE.replace(/'/g, "''") + "'";
        } else {
            sql += P_WHERE_VALUE;
        }

        if (P_ORDER_BY_YN.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
            sql += " order by " + P_ORDER_BY_COLUMN;
        }

        return sql;

    $$
    ;

    -- Where is not a number, so the where condition is single quoted
    select aggregate_string('TABLE_NAME1', 'COL1, COL2, COL3', 'WHERE_COLUMN1', 'WHERE_VALUE', 'Y', 'ORDER_BY_COL1');

    -- Where is a number (whether or not passed in single quotes), so the where condition is not quoted.
    select aggregate_string('TABLE_NAME1', 'COL1, COL2, COL3', 'WHERE_COLUMN1', 5, 'Y', 'ORDER_BY_COL1');

    -- Order by is NO, so there is no order by clause
    select aggregate_string('TABLE_NAME1', 'COL1, COL2, COL3', 'WHERE_COLUMN1', 'WHERE_VALUE', 'N', '');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughtful response - this does just return the SQL statement though correct? This does not actually execute the SQL statement? If I'm understanding the crux of the issue to execute the generated statement I would need to use a sproc, because the UDF does not support dynamic sql?

Comment: Yes, the UDF sample would only generate the statement. I wasn't sure if you wanted just the generation or to execute it. Currently to run SQL in a UDF it needs to be a SQL UDF. The "snowflake" object that's in context in a JavaScript SP is not in context in a JavaScript UDF. I'll see if there's a way to generate and execute using SQL and get back to you.